# Al crear un objeto en Java los valores se cargan en ceros

Tags: java, poo

Intenté crear un objeto en java y noté que no esta cargando los datos iniciales. Es decir, aunque cargue los datos, dichos datos no se cargaron correctamente y quedaron en 0.

dicho codigo para crear el objeto es:

```
        CuentaBancaria cue = new CuentaBancaria();
        System.out.println("INGRESE NUMERO DE CUENTA:");
        cue.setNumeroDeCuenta(sc.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("INGRESE DNI: ");
        cue.setDNI(sc.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("INGRESE SALDO ACTUAL DE LA CUNETA:");
        cue.setSaldoActual(sc.nextFloat());
    }
```

y la llamada en la clase principal es:

```
CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria();
cuenta.crearCuenta();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cada vez que haces new, es un objeto diferente de la misma clase... los datos se estan cargando.. en el lugar donde creaste la clase y la cargaste.. si no pasas esa referencia, la clase simplemente se pierde....

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Sumado a lo que te detallan en el comentario,estas creando un objeto nuevo de la clase CuentaBancaria para poder hacer uso del método `crearCuenta`,el cual a su vez crea un nuevo objeto con valores establecidos por  `Scanner` y el uso de `setters`

```
CuentaBancaria cuenta = new CuentaBancaria();
cuenta.crearCuenta();
```

lo que se debe hacer es darle valores a todo objeto nuevo que sea creado en la clase principal,entonces tu método `crearCuenta` solo debe dar valores mediante el uso de `setters`,espero te ayude la aclaración

```
public void crearCuenta(){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("INGRESE NUMERO DE CUENTA:");
        setNumeroDeCuenta(sc.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("INGRESE DNI: ");
        setDNI(sc.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println("INGRESE SALDO ACTUAL DE LA CUENTA:");
        setSaldoActual(sc.nextFloat());
    }
```